# Curl add backslashes

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I tried to pass array to curl parameters but curl add backslashes to the request.

**Php code :**

```
$domain = 'website.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.com/x.json?domains='[\"".$domain."\"]'");
```

**The logs :**

```
"GET /x.json?domains='[\"http://website.com\"]' HTTP/1.1" 200 105 "-" "-"
```

As you see the array look like `'[\"http://website.com\"]'` not `'["http://website.com"]'`.

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to pass a value as GET parameter with an url.

Try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://website.com/x.json?domains=".urlencode( '["'.$domain.'"]' ) );
```

Comment: Result : domains=%5B%22http%3A%2F%website.com%22%5D

Comment: In the log it will look like this, but if you print out $_GET['domains'] you will get the JSON Array as String.