# PHP adding backslashes to my CURL command for Facebook Offline Conversions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to write a PHP script based on the instructions here:

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/12/18/lead-ads-offline/

But I'm having issues with a json string passed as a parameter to curl in PHP. It looks like it's adding backslashes ("match_keys":"Invalid keys \"email\" etc.) which are causing the API call to fail.

I've tried playing around with:

```
json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

I've tried a bunch of SO answers already like [Curl add backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159922/curl-add-backslashes) but no luck.

```
<?php

$email = hash('sha256', 'test@gmail.com');

$data = array("match_keys" => '{"email": $email}',
              "event_time" =>1477632399,
              "event_name"=> "Purchase",
              "currency"=> "USD",
              "value"=> 2.00);

$fields = [
            // 'upload_tag'=>'2016-10-28-conversions',
            'access_token'=>'#######',
            'data'=> $data
        ];


$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/#######/events';

echo httpPost($url, $fields);


function httpPost($url, $fields)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}


?>
```

This is the response:

```
Array{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_data":{"match_keys":"Invalid keys \"email\" were found in param \"data[match_keys]\".","event_time":"Out of bounds array access: invalid index match_keys","event_name":"Out of bounds array access: invalid index match_keys","currency":"Out of bounds array access: invalid index match_keys","value":"Out of bounds array access: invalid index match_keys"},"fbtrace_id":"BrVDnZPR99A"}}%
```

Comment: How did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JSON in with PHP arrays. I doubt it's actually JSON you intend using to send your data, since you're using `http_build_query`. Try this:

```
$data = array("match_keys" => ["email" => $email], 
  "event_time" =>1477632399,
  "event_name"=> "Purchase",
  "currency"=> "USD",
  "value"=> 2.00
);
```

With this, you define your data as an array, and leave `http_build_query` to do the encoding for you.